# exec() not displaying correct output

Tags: php, exec

I am running this test code using exec() in PHP

```
exec('#!/bin/bash');
exec('abc=10');
echo exec('echo $abc'); // no output

echo exec('whoami'); // this works fine
```

If I run the first 3 lines in terminal, the output is '10'.
But PHP does not output anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does php.ini allow shell access? Additionally, your third call doesn't need an echo statement. It will automatically echo $abc due to the shell command you're issuing.

Comment: If I run `echo exec('whoami');` it displays the output properly.

Comment: Is `abc=10` just a typo? it should be `$abc=10`...

Comment: @webeno That's actually false, webeno. For shell variables you don't need the $ when setting them. That's only when accessing them.

Comment: Not a problem ;) Trips a lot of people up

Comment: @Abhishek I do believe, and I could be wrong, that exec() starts a new shell session each time you run it, so the variable abc will not exist on the second run.

Comment: @Zarathuztra Oh I see...I will try creating a simple script and running it. Thanks.

Comment: @Zarathuztra is correct

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
Manual says use output_arr to capture output.

```
<?php
Exec ($cmd, $output_arr);
Print_r ( $output_arr);
?>
```

@zarathuztra is right. Try combining the various commands in a single exec with ; in between.  Also check my answer if output_arr gets what you want.

Comment: `<?php
Exec('#!/bin/bash; abc=10; echo $abc;', $output_arr);
Print_r ($output_arr);
?>` displays an empty array()